# My Blog is marked as spam because of adBrite

Tags: spam, blogger

I was blogging for over a month. I never thought of publishing ads in my blog until I was recommended to adBrite. I copied the widget code and just added it to my blog. Crap, suddenly I got a message that I was stopped from blogging because it is marked as spam. I never gave up my try, I just kept on sending request to retrieve my blog.

How do I get my blogger blog unlocked and not considered spam?

Answer (score 2):

You should login to your adBrite account and set what type of ads to display. Also you should know that some of the ad's may disqualify your site from being accepted into some other ad networks and affiliate networks. So be careful about what type of ad's you display. Type being popup, popunder, peel away etc. Another problem sometimes with those networks is advertisers exploiting the way ads are published and pushing malware through the javascript to the network.

Removing adBrite would be your best bet, let your site get a clean name for a few months, then apply for AdSense.

Answer (score 0):

Ummm I think you should contact the admin of the website in which site you are blogging. Send a mail to them and request to remove the promotion and keep your blog and give permission for blogging again. I think it will be done.